# Telerik RadCartesianChart BarSeries Style

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a Radcartesianchart of Bar Series in telerik WPF, the values of each Bar is a percentage from two values, and i need change the bar color to red if this value is less than 98%, and need change the bar color to green if the value is over 97%, but all things i have saw about it change the color of all bars in serie, and not happens the bar less than my goal percent, someone can help in this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finished this working with StyleSelector to Barseries.

```
public override Style SelectStyle(object item,
            DependencyObject container)
        {
            if (SetColor)
            {
                Style st = new Style();
                var _item = (item as CategoricalDataPoint);
                st.TargetType = typeof(Border);
                Setter backGroundSetter = new Setter();
                backGroundSetter.Property = Border.BackgroundProperty;

                if (_item.Value < 98)
                {
                    backGroundSetter.Value = Brushes.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    backGroundSetter.Value = Brushes.Lime;
                }
                st.Setters.Add(backGroundSetter);
                return st;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

Ande setting this in the Barseries parameters

```
RadChart.Series.Add(new BarSeries()
                {
                    ShowLabels = true,
                    ClipToPlotArea = true,
                    DefaultVisualStyleSelector = editor.selector,
                    ItemsSource = editor.ItemSourceOptions[i],
                    ValueBinding = new PropertyNameDataPointBinding(editor.SeriesItemsNames[i]),
                    CategoryBinding = new PropertyNameDataPointBinding(editor.CategoryNames[i])
                });
```